# How to use * to import in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, web, import, safari

I have a web application where I use it, as in the example below.

```
import * as b from './library/library.js';
```

Everything is working as it should in Windows, Linux, Android with Chrome and Firefox,
but I noticed that it wasn’t working on Safari on the Iphone and Mac, it also didn’t work
on iPhone's Chrome, all of them.

I looked without a console and was returning this error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'as'. Expected 'from' before exported module name.
```

I did some tests and found that the problem only happens when using the asterisk * to import all the functions of the module at once, as in the example below;

```
import * as name from "module-name"; // This way of the error.

import {export} from "module-name"; // That works OK.
```

Does anyone know how to explain the problem in Safari, or if there is a solution?

I need to import in this generic way, because there are many small functions that
I export this library in addition to using it on all pages of the System,
so it wouldn’t be very practical to have to name each function that I’m importing on each page
of the system.

I already appreciate who can help.

Comment: I am seeing this too, but only in slightly older versions of safari.  My coworker gets it in Safari 14.0.3, but I don't in 14.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is really in asterisk, then I would recommend using default import. A lot of libraries provide them. `import b from './library/library.js';`.

If not, I would recommend using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transform code with modules to code without them. Also, I would recommend using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which provides tree shaking and removes redundant megabytes of library codes from your resulting artefact.

All in all, babel is the best variant in your case.

Comment: But I really needed to use the * asterisks to maintain my system correctly, I don't understand why the safari doesn't accept it and it's not written anywhere.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're not using an `export * as namespace` somewhere?  This is not supported by safari (until maybe 14.1, in my own testing), and will give the error that you mention above.  https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_export_namespace.

Also note, on iOS, every browser, even Chrome, is a wrapper around the webkit (safari) engine.